# (.1f+.2f==.3f) != (.1f+.2f).Equals(.3f) Why?

Tags: c#, equality, floating-accuracy

My question is **not** about floating precision. It is about why `Equals()` is different from `==`.

I understand why `.1f + .2f == .3f` is `false` (while `.1m + .2m == .3m` is `true`).
I get that `==` is reference and `.Equals()` is value comparison. (*Edit*: I know there is more to this.)

But why is `(.1f + .2f).Equals(.3f)` `true`, while `(.1d+.2d).Equals(.3d)` is still `false`?

```
 .1f + .2f == .3f;              // false
(.1f + .2f).Equals(.3f);        // true
(.1d + .2d).Equals(.3d);        // false
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c) provides more details to the differences between floating point and decimal types.

Comment: Just for the record, no real answer:
`Math.Abs(.1d + .2d - .3d) < double.Epsilon`
This should be the better equality method.

Comment: FYI `==` is _not_ "reference" comparison, and `.Equals()` is _not_ "value" comparison. Their implementation is type-specific.

Comment: I believe the reason is constant propagation with the `==` case, using  higher precision to calculated the result. Hence the result is the same as doing the comparison using double precision.

Comment: The key insight here is that `float + float == float` or `double + double == double` _could_ be false when it _appears_ to be true.

Comment: @AustinSalonen: only when dealing with constants.

Comment: Just to clarify: the difference is that in the first case `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` that is a *constant expression* which can be entirely computed at compile time. In `(0.1 + 0.2).Equals(0.3)` the `0.1 + 0.2` and the `0.3` are all constant expressions but the equality is computed by the runtime, not by the compiler. Is that clear?

Comment: Also, just to be picky: the differences that cause the computation to be performed in higher precision need not be "environmental"; the compiler and runtime are both permitted to use higher precision *for any reason whatsoever* irrespective of any environmental details. As a practicality, the decision of when to use higher precision vs lower precision actually usually depends on register availability; expressions that are enregistered are higher precision.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The question is confusingly worded. Let's break it down into many smaller questions:

> Why is it that one tenth plus two tenths does not always equal three tenths in floating point arithmetic?

Let me give you an analogy. Suppose we have a math system where all numbers are rounded off to exactly five decimal places. Suppose you say:

```
x = 1.00000 / 3.00000;
```

You would expect x to be 0.33333, right? Because that is the *closest* number in our system to the *real* answer. Now suppose you said

```
y = 2.00000 / 3.00000;
```

You'd expect y to be 0.66667, right? Because again, that is the *closest* number in our system to the *real* answer. 0.66666 is *farther* from two thirds than 0.66667 is.

Notice that in the first case we rounded down and in the second case we rounded up.

Now when we say

```
q = x + x + x + x;
r = y + x + x;
s = y + y;
```

what do we get?  If we did exact arithmetic then each of these would obviously be four thirds and they would all be equal. But they are not equal. Even though 1.33333 is the closest number in our system to four thirds, only r has that value.

q is 1.33332 -- because x was a little bit small, every addition accumulated that error and the end result is quite a bit too small.  Similarly, s is too big; it is 1.33334, because y was a little bit too big.  r gets the right answer because the too-big-ness of y is cancelled out by the too-small-ness of x and the result ends up correct.

> Does the number of places of precision have an effect on the magnitude and direction of the error?

Yes; more precision makes the magnitude of the error smaller, but can change whether a calculation accrues a loss or a gain due to the error. For example:

```
b = 4.00000 / 7.00000;
```

b would be 0.57143, which rounds up from the true value of 0.571428571... Had we gone to eight places that would be 0.57142857, which has far, far smaller magnitude of error but in the opposite direction; it rounded down.

Because changing the precision can change whether an error is a gain or a loss in each individual calculation, this can change whether a given aggregate calculation's errors reinforce each other or cancel each other out. The net result is that sometimes a lower-precision computation is closer to the "true" result than a higher-precision computation because in the lower-precision computation *you get lucky and the errors are in different directions.*

> We would expect that doing a calculation in higher precision always gives an answer closer to the true answer, but this argument shows otherwise. This explains why sometimes a computation in floats gives the "right" answer but a computation in doubles -- which have twice the precision -- gives the "wrong" answer, correct?

Yes, this is exactly what is happening in your examples, except that instead of five digits of decimal precision we have a certain number of digits of *binary* precision. Just as one-third cannot be accurately represented in five -- or any finite number -- of decimal digits, 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 cannot be accurately represented in any finite number of binary digits. Some of those will be rounded up, some of them will be rounded down, and whether or not additions of them *increase* the error or *cancel out* the error depends on the specific details of **how many binary digits** are in each system. That is, changes in *precision* can change the *answer* for better or worse. Generally the higher the precision, the closer the answer is to the true answer, but not always.

> How can I get accurate decimal arithmetic computations then, if float and double use binary digits?

If you require accurate decimal math then use the `decimal` type; it uses decimal fractions, not binary fractions. The price you pay is that it is considerably larger and slower. And of course as we've already seen, fractions like one third or four sevenths are not going to be represented accurately. Any fraction that is actually a decimal fraction however will be represented with zero error, up to about 29 significant digits.

> OK, I accept that all floating point schemes introduce inaccuracies due to representation error, and that those inaccuracies can sometimes accumulate or cancel each other out based on the number of bits of precision used in the calculation. Do we at least have the guarantee that those inaccuracies will be *consistent*?

No, you have no such guarantee for floats or doubles. The compiler and the runtime are both permitted to perform floating point calculations in *higher* precision than is required by the specification. In particular, the compiler and the runtime are permitted to do single-precision (32 bit) arithmetic *in 64 bit or 80 bit or 128 bit or whatever bitness greater than 32 they like*.

The compiler and the runtime are permitted to do so *however they feel like it at the time*. They need not be consistent from machine to machine, from run to run, and so on. Since this can only make calculations *more accurate* this is not considered a bug. It's a feature. A feature that makes it incredibly difficult to write programs that behave predictably, but a feature nevertheless.

> So that means that calculations performed at compile time, like the literals 0.1 + 0.2, can give different results than the same calculation performed at runtime with variables?

Yep.

> What about comparing the results of `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` to `(0.1 + 0.2).Equals(0.3)`?

Since the first one is computed by the compiler and the second one is computed by the runtime, and I just said that they are permitted to arbitrarily use more precision than required by the specification at their whim, yes, those can give different results. Maybe one of them chooses to do the calculation only in 64 bit precision whereas the other picks 80 bit or 128 bit precision for part or all of the calculation and gets a difference answer.

> So hold up a minute here. You're saying not only that `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` can be different than `(0.1 + 0.2).Equals(0.3)`. You're saying that `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` can be computed to be true or false entirely at the whim of the compiler. It could produce true on Tuesdays and false on Thursdays, it could produce true on one machine and false on another, it could produce both true and false if the expression appeared twice in the same program. This expression can have either value for any reason whatsoever; the compiler is permitted to be *completely* unreliable here.

Correct.

The way this is usually reported to the C# compiler team is that someone has some expression that produces true when they compile in debug and false when they compile in release mode. That's the most common situation in which this crops up because the debug and release code generation changes register allocation schemes. But the compiler is *permitted* to do anything it likes with this expression, so long as it chooses true or false. (It cannot, say, produce a compile-time error.)

> This is craziness.

Correct.

> Who should I blame for this mess?

Not me, that's for darn sure.

Intel decided to make a floating point math chip in which it was far, far more expensive to make consistent results. Small choices in the compiler about what operations to enregister vs what operations to keep on the stack can add up to big differences in results.

> How do I ensure consistent results?

Use the `decimal` type, as I said before. Or do all your math in integers.

> I have to use doubles or floats; can I do *anything* to encourage consistent results?

Yes. If you store any result into any *static field*, any *instance field of a class* or *array element* of type float or double then it is guaranteed to be truncated back to 32 or 64 bit precision. (This guarantee is expressly *not* made for stores to locals or formal parameters.) Also if you do a *runtime* cast to `(float)` or `(double)` on an expression that is already of that type then the compiler will emit special code that forces the result to truncate as though it had been assigned to a field or array element. (Casts which execute at compile time -- that is, casts on constant expressions -- are not guaranteed to do so.)

> To clarify that last point: does the C# *language specification* make those guarantees?

No. The *runtime* guarantees that stores into an array or field truncate. The C# specification does not guarantee that an identity cast truncates but the Microsoft implementation has regression tests that ensure that every new version of the compiler has this behaviour.

All the language spec has to say on the subject is that floating point operations may be performed in higher precision at the discretion of the implementation.

Comment: Problem happens when we assign bool result= 0.1f+0.2f==0.3f. When we don't store 0.1f+0.2f in a variable we get false. If we store 0.1f+0.2f in variable we get true. It has little to do with general floating point arithmetic if any, basically main question here is why bool x=0.1f+0.2f==0.3f is false, but float temp=0.1f+0.2f; bool x=temp==0.3f is true, rest is usual floating point question part

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: There is no temp variable in `==` case as the result is determined at compile-time.

Comment: When _Eric Lippert_ answered the same question with me, I always feel `damn! my answer doesn't look logical anymore..`

Comment: @leppie edited my comment a little as I don't quite get what happens there, IE I cannot figure out what statement would return true for right part of equation except 0.1f+0.2f==0.1f+0.2f

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: I edited my answer a little. Can you see the difference now?

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: You are correct; I've updated my answer considerably to address your concerns.

Comment: I really appreciate how you still take the time and have the patience to contribute such a carefully written and a rather lengthy post, for a question which probably pops once a week. +1

Comment: Eric does give a good account as to why `0.1f+0.2f==0.3f` is compiled to `false`, but I will note the same expression `0.1f+0.2f = 0.3f` compiles to `True` in VB.NET. Otherwise, Decimal and Double both return the same results for C# and VB.NET.

Comment: @MarkHurd: I think you're not getting the full impact of what I'm saying here. It's not a question of what the C# compiler or the VB compiler does. The C# compiler is permitted to give *either answer* to that question *at any time for any reason*. You can compile the same program twice and get different answers. You can ask the question twice in the same program and get two different answers.  C# and VB do not produce "the same results" because C# *and C#* does not necessarily produce the same results.  If they happen to produce the same results, that's a lucky coincidence.

Comment: What an answer. This is why I use StackOverflow.

Answer (score 8):

When you write

```
double a = 0.1d;
double b = 0.2d;
double c = 0.3d;
```

*Actually*, these are not exactly `0.1`, `0.2` and `0.3`. From IL code;

```
  IL_0001:  ldc.r8     0.10000000000000001
  IL_000a:  stloc.0
  IL_000b:  ldc.r8     0.20000000000000001
  IL_0014:  stloc.1
  IL_0015:  ldc.r8     0.29999999999999999
```

There are a lof of question in SO pointing that issue like ([Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/618535/447156) and [Dealing with floating point errors in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2248748/69809)) but I suggest you to read cool article called;

[`What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

*Well*, what leppie [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117472/447156) is more logical. The real situation is here, **totaly depends** on `compiler` / `computer` or `cpu`.

Based on leppie code, this code works on my *Visual Studio 2010* and *Linqpad*, as a result `True`/`False`, but when I tried it on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/), the result will be `True`/`True`

Check the **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Q3gZQw)**.

*Tip*: When I wrote `Console.WriteLine(.1f + .2f == .3f);` Resharper warnings me;

> Comparison of floating points number with equality operator. Possible
>   loss of precision while rounding values.

[image]

Comment: He is asking about the single precision case. There is no issue with double precision case.

Comment: Apparently there's a difference between the code that will be executed and the compiler too. `0.1f+0.2f==0.3f` will be compiled to false in both debug and release mode. Therefor it will be false for the equality-operator.

Answer (score 5):

As said in the comments, this is due to the compiler doing constant propagation and performing the calculation at a higher precision (I believe this is CPU dependent).

```
  var f1 = .1f + .2f;
  var f2 = .3f;
  Console.WriteLine(f1 == f2); // prints true (same as Equals)
  Console.WriteLine(.1f+.2f==.3f); // prints false (acts the same as double)
```

@Caramiriel also points out that `.1f+.2f==.3f` is emit as `false` in the IL, hence the compiler did the calculation at compile-time.

To confirm the constant folding/propagation compiler optimization

```
  const float f1 = .1f + .2f;
  const float f2 = .3f;
  Console.WriteLine(f1 == f2); // prints false
```

Comment: But why doesn't it do the same optimization in the last case?

Comment: @SonerGönül: Soon to be eclipsed by his highness ;p Thanks

Comment: Ok, let me state it more clearly, as I was referring to OP's last case: **But why doesn't it do the same optimization in the `Equals` case?**

Comment: @Groo: if you mean `(0.1d+.2d).Equals(.3d) == false`, because IT IS!

Comment: No, I didn't mean `(0.1d+.2d).Equals(.3d) == false`, I meant `(.1f + .2f).Equals(.3f) == true` vs `((.1f + .2f) == (.3f)) == false`. But I didn't catch that last IL-related line initially, now it makes sense. I first thought you were saying that `.1f+.2f` gets calculated at compile time and didn't see why it wouldn't be done in the `float.Equals` case also, but actually the *comparison* also gets done while compiling, which doesn't happen with the `Equals` method.

Comment: @Groo: See the last bit of Eric's answer.

Comment: @Groo : because in the case of the Equals, it is a function that is related to an instance. The specifics can change at runtime if you subtype Float.

Comment: @njzk2: well, `float` is a `struct`, so it cannot be subclassed. And a float constant has a pretty constant `Equals` implementation, too.

Comment: @Groo : good point, but i don't know how much the compiler considers regarding the fact that float is a struct and that the target is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW following test passes

```
float x = 0.1f + 0.2f;
float result = 0.3f;
bool isTrue = x.Equals(result);
bool isTrue2 = x == result;
Assert.IsTrue(isTrue);
Assert.IsTrue(isTrue2);
```

So problem is actually with this line

> 0.1f + 0.2f==0.3f

Which as stated is probably compiler/pc specific

Most people are jumping at this question from wrong angle I think so far

**UPDATE:**

Another curious test I think

```
const float f1 = .1f + .2f;
const float f2 = .3f;
Assert.AreEqual(f1, f2); passes
Assert.IsTrue(f1==f2); doesnt pass
```

Single equality implementation:

```
public bool Equals(float obj)
{
    return ((obj == this) || (IsNaN(obj) && IsNaN(this)));
}
```

Comment: I agree with your last statement :)

Comment: @leppie updated my answer with new test. Can you tell me why 1st passes and second doesn't. I dont quite understand, given Equals implementation

Answer (score 0):

`==` is about comparing exact floats values.

`Equals` is a boolean method that may return true or false. The specific implementation may vary.

Comment: check my answer for float Equals implementation. Actual difference is that equals is performed at runtime, while == can be performed at compile time, == is also a "boolean method" (I heard more about boolean functions), practically

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but at this time some results of mine are different from yours. Note the third and fourth test happens to be contrary to the problem, so parts of your explanations might be wrong now.

```cs
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        float a = .1f + .2f;
        float b = .3f;
        Console.WriteLine(a == b);                 // true
        Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));            // true
        Console.WriteLine(.1f + .2f == .3f);       // true
        Console.WriteLine((1f + .2f).Equals(.3f)); //false
        Console.WriteLine(.1d + .2d == .3d);       //false
        Console.WriteLine((1d + .2d).Equals(.3d)); //false
    }
}
```