# IEEE floating point Numbers

Tags: ieee-754, cpu-architecture

I studied IEEE floating point number from the following link

[IEEE floating Point Number](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html)

In the above article, I am not clear behind the logic of special operation. Why they have decided the special operation in this way (means why Infinity-Infinity is Nan) and all the others also.

If anyone know, Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` is something like “error” or “unknown”. Every operation with `NaN` results in `NaN`. `Infinity` and `-Infinity` are introduced to handle overflow in a well-defined way. When overflow happens, you cannot be sure about how much it happened. Therefore two infinite values can be in fact different. Therefore `Infinity - Infinity` does not have any well-defined value, which is handled by `NaN`.

C example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main() {
    double e, f;

    /* floats are always implicitly converted to doubles for computation */
    /* but intermediate values can be larger */
    e = DBL_MAX * 2.0;
    f = DBL_MAX * 2.5;
    printf("%-12s%e\n", "DBL_MAX",    DBL_MAX);
    printf("%-12s%e\n", "e",          e);
    printf("%-12s%e\n", "f",          f);
    printf("%-12s%e\n", "f - e",      f - e);
    printf("%-12s%e\n", "f - e expr", DBL_MAX * 2.5 - DBL_MAX * 2.0);

    return 0;
}
```

Output (GCC 4.3.2, Linux 2.6.26-2-686):

```
DBL_MAX     1.79769e+308
e           inf
f           inf
f - e       nan
f - e expr  8.98847e+307
```

The last expression is a tricky one. Why this happens is described elsewhere. Basically the intermediate calculation is done in a larger type.

- [Why does these two code variants produce different floating-point results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15490061/2157640)
- [Intermediate Floating-Point Precision @ #AltDevBlog](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/03/22/intermediate-floating-point-precision/)