# Understanding the given calculation (cast + multiplication)

Tags: c#, .net, casting

```
(int)((float)10.9 * 10)
```

is evaluated to `108`. Why?

IMO the `(int)`-cast should be evaluated *after* the multiplication.

Comment: You run into floating point calculation precision issue.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you've learn so far about floating point so we know where to start explanation (obviously you've searched for something like "C# what programer should know about flaoting point" - i.e. http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html - so feel free to add results of your research to the post).

Comment: @Joey you should undlete your answer, the answer to Sriam's comment on your answer is "it is because when you use a single statement the compiler actually evaluates it as `double f =((float)10.9 * 10);int i = (int)f;` it will use a double for the intermediate value."

Comment: Either use `Math.Round` when converting to `int`, or switch to `decimal` if you are dealing with currencies or other values with fit into the base-10 system naturally.

Comment: @Scott: shouldn't `var f` make the variable a `float`? I think the difference is that in the first case, entire expression is evaluated at compile time and replaced by an integer literal in MSIL. The other expression has two variables, so casting is done at runtime, hence the difference. But Joey's answer *is* correct, it's just that you can't rely on this behavior to be consistent.

Comment: Argh floating-point arithmetic.. I'll _probably_ never fully understand you.

Comment: @SonerGönül - I agree with you. It really seems like `short` and `float` are just significantly more dangerous than their longer counterparts.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: It appears someone else did that for me already. Quite confusing to come to work and see a bunch of comments to an answer you thought you deleted earlier ...

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain that's it. Casting `float` to `double` will just add meaningless digits, and `double` is like 'hey, look at how precise I am'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(.1f+.2f==.3f) != (.1f+.2f).Equals(.3f) Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117037/1f-2f-3f-1f-2f-equals-3f-why)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is exactly the case. It's just that 10.9 is *slightly* less than 10.9 due to the way floating point numbers are represented (10.9 cannot be represented exactly, so you get an approximation, which in this case is something like 10.89999999...). The cast then truncates any digits following the decimal point. So you get 108.

Exact values are as follows here (obtained with Jon Skeet's [DoubleConverter](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) class):

```
10.9         -> 10.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625
(float) 10.9 -> 10.8999996185302734375
```

Multiplying that float by 10 and then cutting off all decimal places will obviously result in 108.

Comment: Umm I don't understand then why splitting it into two statements works expected. `var f =((float)10.9 * 10);int i = (int)f;` gives 109 and 109

Comment: But why do i get `109` instead of `108.9999...` when I do the following:
    `((float)10.9 * 10).ToString()`

Comment: Because `ToString` rounds, whereas casting to int truncates.

Comment: @Lasse: Why should ToString() round, when not given a format string?

Comment: It just does. I don't know why they decided to do it like that.

Comment: @Lasse: Then why evaluates `((float)10.9*10).ToString("0.000")` to `109.000` instead of `108.999` ?

Comment: @thomai: because the value is larger than `108.999`. Just like you would expect `108.0009` to be rounded to `108.001`.

Comment: It does rounding. The problem here is that everyone is trying to make sense of why floating point calculations does or does not make sense at this level of precision. The problem is that **they don't**. Smart people have tried to "fix" this problem for decades but it isn't possible because we have a finite number of bits available to store numbers that cannot be exactly represented in the way we're representing them, with bits. If you need to be able to reason about the behavior, you need to use `decimal`. Otherwise, there **will be** inaccuracies.

Comment: Personally I think this question here should be closed and linked to a duplicate just like "What is a null reference exception and how do I fix it" because the answers are invariably the same. Accept the inaccuracies, deal with them the best you can, and if you can't accept it, switch to a different data type that gives you the level of precision you can accept.

Comment: @Groo: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there a way to display the exact value of a float? Because that's what I want to archieve with the ToString().

Comment: @thomai That question doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "exact value of a float"? What's the exact value of `10 / 3`?

Comment: In the `10 / 3`-example I want to find out what's the actual, internal value of the float. Probably something like `3.33333412`.
The method should take the internal bits of the float and convert them to decimal without rounding (like ToString() does)

Comment: @thomai: You can use [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s [DoubleConverter class](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) which has a `ToExactString` method. The code could easily be adapted to `float` instead, but `float` works exactly the same, just with fewer decimal digits.

Answer (score 11):

Amusingly enough, the issue here is that the expression is calculated at compile time, apparently using single precision math as expected. This happens in both debug and release builds:

```
    // this replaces the whole operation
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.s 108
    IL_0003: stloc.0
    IL_0004: ldloc.0
    IL_0005: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
```

While the case `var f =((float)10.9 * 10);int i = (int)f;` is still optimized for the multiplication, but using double precision. Because the cast is done in a separate step I guess it confuses the compiler (??):

```
    IL_000b: ldc.r4 109      // 109 result for the first part
    IL_0010: stloc.1
    IL_0011: ldloc.1
    IL_0012: conv.i4         // separate conversion to int
    IL_0013: stloc.2
    // rest is printing it
    IL_0014: ldloc.1
    IL_0015: box [mscorlib]System.Single
    IL_001a: ldstr " "
    IL_001f: ldloc.2
    IL_0020: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_0025: call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object, object, object)
    IL_002a: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

Honestly I'd say the compiler is generating wrong code in the second case, which is probably why C++ avoids optimizing floating point code like the plague. Luckily, this is only an issue for this kind of test code which can be done fully at compile time, actual variable multiplication would be fine.

I actually tried this too:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)(float.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) * int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())));
```

and gave it 10.9 and 10, and the result was 108 as expected.

Comment: *...and the result was 108 as expected*. You have to love floating point.

Comment: I don't think that was ever in question, it's the fact that when broken in steps it gives 109 that's the weird thing. The compiler does the calculation internally using the wrong (better, but still wrong) type.

Comment: However, `var z = 10; var f = (10.9f * z); int i = (int)f;` does do the multiplication (in IL) but still evaluates to 109. I feel like the jitter must be doing something fun.

Comment: @EricLippert, I'd be curious to hear your thoughts on this subject. There's a lot of funky stuff going on here.

Answer (score 3):

Your `float` result, before casting to int, is 108.9999 because 109.0000 [can't be represented in floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx). *(As mentioned in comments, that's wrong; 109 can be represented just fine, but somehow the expression results in 108.9999 -- the following still applies)*

The `int` value will be 108. Why? Casting from floating point (`double` or `float`) to `int` truncates the decimal part. It doesn't round. So it cuts off the .9999 and you get 108.

To round, replace the cast by `Math.Round()` or `Convert.ToInt32()`.

```
Convert.ToInt32((float) 10.9 * 10);
```

Comment: http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html sais, that "Mathematical operations like these will give you exact results as long as all of the values are integers smaller than 2^24".
109 is way smaller than 2^24...

Comment: Yeah, Kay is wrong, 109 can be represented fine. It's the multiplication itself that isn't precise enough.

Comment: Although @Blindy is correct, +1 for mentioning `Convert.ToInt32`. I didn't know it rounds, that's a good thing.

Comment: @thomai: that is only true if you are dealing solely with integers. The paragraph starts with `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`.

Comment: It's the 10.9 which can't be represented, so it is replaced with 10.8999999. Multilying it with 10 afterwards won't help there any longer.