# Variable acting strange(like floating point )

Tags: c#, point, floating

I have this code;

```
 static int test = 100;
        static int Test
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)(test * 0.01f);
            }
        }
```

output is : 0

But this code returns different

```
static int test = 100;
    static int Test
    {
        get
        {
            var y = (test * 0.01f);
            return (int)y;
        }
    }
```

output is : 1

Also I have this code

```
  static int test = 100;
    static int Test
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)(100 * 0.01f);
        }
    }
```

output is : 1

I look at IL output and I dont understand why C# doing this mathematical operation at compile time and output different? [image]

What is difference of this two code? Why I decided to use variable result is changing?

Comment: How do you check values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I was looking around an SO, but I can't find the exact answer. This answer however, may clear things up a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15117741/2594485

Comment: My question about compile time operations,variables and casting.Why compiler doing this operation at compile time.Why if I choose to use variable,result is changing?

Comment: Storing a value in a variable is done at runtime. It could be converted back and forth. And since floating-point arithmetic is inaccurate, apparently it can result in a value that is slightly less than 1. If the compiler sees `100 * 0.01`, it will do the calculation at compile-time. Why? Because.

Comment: It's not "like" floating point - it is about floating point. It's about whether a calculated value is being stored with 80-bits of precision (as required when the value is *stored* in a variable) vs more precision, and is very well handled in Eric Lippert's answer, as linked to by Dennis.

Comment: Let me take a look.Thanks for reply.

Comment: It is permitted that the results be different *at any time for any reason*. Is this terrible? Yes. But which way a thing rounds depends on tiny, tiny differences in the value, and you are generating tiny differences.

Answer (score 2):

Because the compiler tricks you. The compiler is smart enough to do some math already so it doesn't need to do that on run-time, which would be pointless. The expression `100 * .01f` is calculated in the compiler, without the lack of precision on the float, which [breaks you up on run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/993547).

To prove this, try to make the `static test` a `const`. You will see the compiler is able to do the math for you on compile time then too. It has nothing with writing to a variable first, as in your sample. Run-time vs. compile-time is.

Comment: Ok I understand.But this is not my question.I get it.Compiler solving 
constant matematical operations at compile time.This is really need to be.But if I use variables for this operation "result" is changing? I think this is a wrong? Why result is changing.Variables just a placeholder am I right?

Comment: No. There is a difference between compile time resolution of constant values and runtime representation.