# Which numeric type conversion is better for simple math operation?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, precision, numeric

I want to know which conversion is better (regarding performance/speed and precision/most less loss) for a simple math operation and what makes them different?

Example:

```
double double1 = integer1 / (5 * integer2);
var double2 = integer1 / (5.0 * integer2);
var double3 = integer1 / (5D * integer2);
var double4 = (double) integer1 / (5 * integer2);
var double5 = integer1 / (double) (5 * integer2);
var double6 = integer1 / ((double) 5 * integer2);
var double7 = integer1 / (5 * (double) integer2);
var double8 = Convert.ToDouble(integer1 / (5 * integer2));
var double9 = integer1 / Convert.ToDouble(5 * integer2);
```

Actually my question is about the conversion not the type itself.

Comment: `float1`, `float8` will use integer division so you can straight away forget about those two. About the rest, it really depends on what the values of `integer1` and `integer2` are. I think you need to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15117741/767890). Performance wise, there is no reason for `double9`, it is esentially the same as `double5` but slower due to the added indirection.

Comment: Good link about float operations.

Comment: If I had to bet for the *marginal* winner *performance wise*, I'd choose `double4` or `double5` and from those two, simply due to readability, I'd choose `double4`.

Comment: While asking for performance and accuracy given example shows you don't understand some basics of equations in C# (not sure which word is correct to name it, therefore a comment). The keypoint here is which *type* compiler will use when calculating it. You should carefully think how result will be calculated when composing equation, taking order of precedence in account. The best of course is to look at produced IL (if you can read and understand it). Otherwise use *safe* option, in your case it is (as for me 100% clean) `var result = integer1 / 5d * integer2`.

Comment: @Sinatr I didn't understand the produced IL and could not express it in my question precisely. Matthew Watson has given very good points. Therefore I take his as answer and thank to him a lot :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

In response to your totally changed question:

The first line `double double1 = integer1 / (5 * integer2);` does an integer division, so don't do that.

Also the line `var double8 = Convert.ToDouble(integer1 / (5 * integer2));` is doing integer division before converting the result to a double, so don't do that either.

Other than that, all the different approaches you list will end up calling the IL instruction `Conv.R8` once for each line in your sample code.

The only real difference is that `Convert.ToDouble()` will make a method call to do so, so you should avoid that.

The results for every line other than `double1` and `double8` will be identical.

So you should probably go for the simplest: `var double2 = integer1 / (5.0 * integer2);`

In a more complicated situation, time your code to see if there's any differences.

Comment: Is hard type conversion using (double) generally slower or faster than using native number like 5.0 or 5D? comparing for example: var double6 = integer1 / ((double) 5 * integer2);  VS   var double2 = integer1 / (5.0 * integer2);

Comment: @MagB It makes no difference - like I said, all the conversions you listed end up calling `Conv.R8` (and it's only called once for each line of your sample code). In more complicated situations, time your code to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

The differences between your lines of codes are not about conversions, some of them are totally different things and the values are not the same.

```
1.    float float1 = integer1 / (5 * integer2);
```

`5 * interger2` gives an `int`,  `int` divides `int` gives an `int`, and you assign the `int` value to a `float` variable, using implicit conversion because `int` has a small range than `float`. `float float1 = 1 / (5 * 2)`, you will get a `System.Single` 0 as the result.

```
2.    var float2 = integer1 / (5.0 * integer2);
```

`5.0` is essentially `5.0d`, so the type of `float2` is `System.Double`, `var float2 = 1 / (5.0 * 2)` you will get a `System.Double` 0.1 as the result.

```
3.   var float3 = integer1 / (5F * integer2);
```

Using the same values above you will get a `System.Single` 0.1, which is probably what you want.

```
4.   var float4 = (float)integer1 / (5 * integer2);
```

You will get the same as item 3. The difference is item3 is `int divides by float` while item4 is `float divides by int`.

```
5.   var float5 = integer1 / (float) (5 * integer2);
6.   var float6 = integer1 / ((float) 5 * integer2);
7.   var float7 = integer1 / (5 * (float) integer2);
```

The three are almost the same as item 3, it calculates an `int divides by float`, just different ways to build the divider.

```
8.   var float8 = Convert.ToDecimal(integer1 / (5 * integer2));
9.   var float9 = integer1 / Convert.ToDecimal(5 * integer2);
```

The two will give you `System.Decimal` values, which has a higher precision. Item8 has the same issue as item1, you will get 0 because the parameter of `Convert.ToDecimal` is a `int` 0.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of float/decimal use double:

A more generic answer for the generic question "Decimal vs Double": Decimal for monetary calculations to preserve the precision, Double for scientific calculations that do not get affected by small differences. Since Double is a type which is native to the CPU (internal representation is stored in base 2), calculations made with Double perform better then Decimal (which is represented in base 10 internally).